# Splitting a single input and storing in individual variables

Tags: c, split

I am trying to split single input and store in separate variables.

**Given below is my code:**

```
int main() {
    float mil;  
    char car[50];
    scanf("%s@%f", car, &mil);
    printf("%s %f", car, mil);
    return 0;
}
```

**Input:**

```
polo@15.5
```

**The output of the Program:**

```
polo@15.5 0.000000
```

How can I store the name of `car` in `string` and the value of `mileage` in `float` so that the output would be like:

```
polo 15.5
```

Comment: Hint: don't use `scanf`, use `fgets` and parse the input string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `%s` scans everything *until a whitespace character* and not until a `'@'` character.

You can use the `%[` format specifier to get what you want:

```
scanf("%[^@]@%f", car, &mil);
```

`%[^@]` tells `scanf` to scan everything until a `@`.

---

Side note: You should always check the result of `*scanf`. They return the number of elements successfully scanned and assigned. Also, you might as well use a length modifier (`%49[^@]` in your case) to prevent buffer overflows.

Comment: Only to clarify, why is the second @needed? (I am an amateur in C that`s why I am asking)

Comment: @Alan `%[^@]` scans everything _until_ a `@` but doesn't consume that `@`. The second `@` tells `scanf` to scan in the left over `@`.

Comment: So basically the first @ tells `scanf`not to read the `@`, and the second one tells `scanf` that an `@`comes but should be skipped? What do you exactly mean with > but doesn`t consume that @?

Comment: @Alan The first `@` is in the `%[` format specifier which means that it's part of it. The second one isn't and tells to scan a `@` character and skip it.

Comment: Oh okey got it! Thanks!

Comment: @Alan Suppose the input is `abcd@10.5`. After `%[^@]` the data left in the input stream is `@10.5`. The second `@`  causes it to skip the `@` leaving the data in the input stream with `10.5` which finally, is read by `%f`.

Comment: Perfect explanation dude!

Answer (score 2):

Your input is a string so you must first separate it. You can use strtok_s() from the string.h library for this.

```
#include <string.h>
// ...
char * model = NULL;
strtok_s(car, '@', model);
```

Now "polo" is stored in car and "15.5" is stored in model but they are both strings. To convert the model to a float you can use the atof() function included in the standard library (stdlib.h).

```
float mil = atof(model);
```